# VSCode show `unrecognized token` for Objective-C header file

Tags: objective-c, flutter, visual-studio-code

I have tried with edit this file to save as `UTF-8` or `UTF-8 with BOM` but doesn't work.

I have tried install several vscode extensions related to Objective-C but still not work.

What would be the correct way to eliminate this problems.

[image]

#### Update

As @MattBierner suggest, after `copy` and past the `error`:

```
{
    "resource": "[plagin_paht]plugins/packages/path_provider/ios/Classes/PathProviderPlugin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "unrecognized token",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

Comment: What extension is generating those errors? Could be a standard c/c++ extension not understanding objective-c headers

Comment: @MattBierner I don’t know which extension cause this error, how to check ?

Comment: Right click on the error in the problems view and `copy`. Paste to see the full error info

Comment: @MattBierner Just past in question, it's `_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_`

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: em, a lot.. I have enabled 69 extensions in VSCode.

Comment: What ones do you have related to c/objc/c++?

Comment: @MattBierner, ok with your idea, I disable the extension related to `c++` one by one,  and lucky to me, after the first c++ related extension disabled, the error gone.  The extension is `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools`

Comment: There's a issue comment pointed that this extension not support `objective c`: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2533#issuecomment-422923416

Comment: Would you mind provide your suggestions as an answer, so I can mark it as the solution for how to solve this kind of error step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the standard c/c++ extension (vscode-cpptools). It will treat all `.h` files as normal c/c++ headers by default, so objective-c specific syntax will produce an error.

As an alternative, you may also be able to change the [`files.associations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) for `.h` files to mark them specifically as objective-c. Not all extensions will respect the `files.associations` however